# How to select rows that start with a digit in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have page that shows items in an index.

I'm able to get items by letter using the following:

```
scope :by_letter, lambda { |letter| where("name LIKE '#{letter}%'") }
```

But I can't figure out an elegant solution for names that start with a number (0-9).

**How could I rewrite this or a separate scope that would let me search for names starting with a digit?**

**EDIT:** I'm trying to get all rows that start with 0-9 in one go (not separately for each number).

Comment: Did you try `Model.by_letter("1")`. It should work. Just change the name to by_character and you've got it! :)

Comment: Updated the question mark :) -- I meant fetch the rows that start with a digit in one go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work

```
scope :starts_with_number, where("name REGEXP '[0-9]%'")
```

Comment: Awesome! much better than my solution below. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob fixed it to use REGEXP

Answer (score 1):

Jacob, try this slightly rewritten version of what you ended up with:

```
@letter_merchants = (0..9).map { |d| Merchant.by_letter(d) }
```

Please note that this should only illustrate how awesome language Ruby is, not how the problem should be solved (there would be too many database calls).

Comment: Wow, that's pretty awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
@letter_merchants = []
(0..9).to_a.each do |digit|
  @letter_merchants |= Merchant.by_letter(digit)
end
```

Comment: just to be mean => how many queries will be executed by this code?

Answer (score 0):

One disadvantage of REGEXP is that it can't use indexes. however

```
scope :starts_with_number, where("name >= '0' and name < ':')
```

can use an index on name. It does rely on the characters 0-9: being in precisely that order, with nothing in between which will be the case in anything like ascii, utf8 but not if you used ebcdic or anything crazy like that